# Weird tab traversal behavior in wxPython custom control

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

If you make a custom control as a subclass of wx.PyControl, the tab traversal will behave oddly. For example, with the code below, pressing tab a few times will get you stuck inside MyControl. Once you tab to a "Child of MyControl" textbox, you can only tab between the 2 "Child of MyControl" textboxes, and will never tab back to "Child of Panel".

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyFrame, self).__init__(None)
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(wx.TextCtrl(panel, value="Child of Panel"), flag=wx.EXPAND)
    sizer.AddSpacer(30)
    sizer.Add(MyControl(panel), flag=wx.EXPAND)
    panel.SetSizer(sizer)


class MyControl(wx.PyControl):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(MyControl, self).__init__(parent, style=wx.BORDER_NONE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer.Add(wx.TextCtrl(self, value="Child of MyControl"), flag=wx.EXPAND)
    sizer.AddSpacer(10)
    sizer.Add(wx.TextCtrl(self, value="Child of MyControl"), flag=wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the tab traversal to behave in a standard way is surprisingly simple. All you have to do is make your custom control subclass wx.Panel instead of wx.PyControl.

```
class MyControl(wx.Panel):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    super(MyControl, self).__init__(parent)
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, TAB navigation is implemented by [wxPanel](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.0/classwx_panel.html) as mentioned in its description.